# What is the correct plural of "octopus"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, greek

What is the correct plural of *octopus*:

- *Octopi*?
- *Octopodes*?
- *Octopuses*?
- Something else?

Comment: Let's find out from the Merriam-Webster's editor: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFyY2mK8pxk

Comment: Obviously, if one is an *octopus*, two is a *sedecipus*.

Comment: There was a petition on petitiononline.org to change the plural of *walrus* to *walri*. Sadly, that website has gone the way of all things.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I would go  with *octopuses*.

That is part of the [Wikipedia "Plural form of words ending in -us"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural_form_of_words_ending_in_-us#Octopus) article:

> Currently:
>
> - ***octopuses* is the most common form in the UK as well as the US**;
> - *octopodes* is rare,
> - and *octopi* is often objectionable.
>
> The Oxford English Dictionary lists *octopuses, octopi* and *octopodes* (in that order);
>   it labels *octopodes* "rare", and notes that *octopi* derives from the mistaken assumption that *octōpūs* is a second declension Latin noun, which it is not. Rather, it is (Latinized) Ancient Greek, from *oktṓpous* (*ὀκτώπους*), gender masculine, whose plural is *oktṓpodes* (*ὀκτώποδες*).
>   If the word were native to Latin, it would be *octōpēs* ('eight-foot') and the plural *octōpedes*, analogous to *centipedes* and *mīllipedes,* as the plural form of *pēs* ('foot') is *pedes.*
>   In modern Greek, it is called *khtapódi* (*χταπόδι*), gender neuter, with plural form *khtapódia* (*χταπόδια*).

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I just found this entertaining video, as well:

http://www.wimp.com/octopusplural/

I just might have to go around saying octopodes.

Answer (score 48):

As other answers have already pointed out, the correct English plural is *octopuses*.

Some clarification is needed in the answers, though, since many people are under the impression that *octopi* is definitely wrong for historical reasons, while *octopodes* is apparently acceptable (even though almost no one aside from grammar fanatics has ever heard of it).

After reviewing the historical evidence, both *octopi* and *octopodes* have problems.

Aside from the fact that *octopi* is a familiar plural to many and is indeed listed ahead of *octopodes* in almost all (if not all) dictionaries, generally following *octopuses*, there are strong historical reasons why *octopodes* should be suspect.

1. **The word *octopus* did not actually exist in either ancient Greek or ancient Latin**, so appeal to a "native" plural is problematic.  The standard word for the Romans and Greeks to refer to the animal was *polypus/polypous*. (There was a very rare adjective in Greek *oktapous*, also incredibly rare in Latin form as *octipes*, but it merely meant "eight-footed" and did not refer to the creature we now call an octopus.  It's exceedingly unlikely that our modern word came from these roots, as the etymology is explained below.)
2. While the root *octopod-* is suggested by English words like *octopod* and the biological order *Octopoda*, there are also English words drawn from the root *octop-*, such as *octopean*, *octopine*, and *octopic*.  All of these suggest that there is a significant history of educated folks who would accept *octopi* as a reasonable plural.
3. The word *octopus* was coined by Linnaeus (the biologist) in the 18th century, based on a Latinized Greek word *polypus*.  Linnaeus did use the plural *octopodes* in his modern Latin and the root *octopod-* for example in the taxonomic order *Octopoda*.  On the other hand, almost as soon as the word entered the English language, the plural *octopi* begins to be seen.  The OED has a sample quotation from 1834 with *octopi* (only the second English-language quotation in their list), but a cursory search in Google books shows that *octopi* occurred well before that in the early 1800s.  Essentially, **there has really never been a period in the English language where *octopi* didn't co-exist with *octopodes*.**  Most sources from before 1850 or so in English are specialized texts listing off Linnaeus's classifications, but once we begin to see the word *octopus* come into everyday use, *octopi* seems to become a common, if not dominant plural.
4. "Yes," comes the objection, "but it's still wrong.  It doesn't matter how long it's been in the English language.  The word comes from Greek, not Latin."  First off, the word comes from Latin -- if it were Greek, it would be *oktopous* (or maybe *octopous*, if we allow a little fudging in the transliteration).  Yes, *octopus* ultimately comes from Greek roots, but it comes through *Latinized* Greek.  What matters is not how we would decline the word in Greek, but how we would decline the word in Latin.  The argument goes that it would be a third declension noun in Latin, with stem *octopod-*, rather than a second declension noun, with stem *octop-*.  Hence, *octopodes* over *octopi*.  A difficulty with this argument is that **the Latin predecessors, such as *polypus*, from which *octopus* was coined, actually used the second-declension plural form *polypi*.**  Latinized Greek plurals were often not consistent in their declensions, even for the ancient Romans.  Even Linnaeus inconsistently used *polypi* alongside *octopodes*, since he knew his Latin well, and the Romans used *polypi*, not *polypodes*.  Educated ancient Romans, who knew their Greek well, still preferred *polypi*.  Would they object to *octopi*?  I don't know, but when your plural form is actually inconsistent with the plural of the original word used as a basis, the historical argument gets more murky.  (I would also suggest that some educated English speakers and writers in the late 1700s and early 1800s who encountered *octopus* for the first time could have known that the Latin word for the animal was *polypus*, and they may have assumed *octopus* would form *octopi* as a plural as well.)
5. "Okay," comes a final objection, "but Linnaeus knew his Greek, and we do too.  If the word ultimately came from Greek, we should use the 'proper' way to pluralize the Latin version, even if the ancient Romans didn't know any better."  Ah, but there's a further problem.  **The ancient Greeks weren't consistent in choosing a declension for *polypous*.**  In addition to *polypodes*, one can easily find examples of *polypoi*, which would probably be the reason the Romans used *polypi*.

Is *octopodes* "wrong"?  No, I don't think so.  But arguing for an analogy to native Latin or ancient Greek plurals is misguided in this case.  For this specific example, the likely form that the Romans would have used (if they coined the word) could have easily been *octopi*, particularly if they thought of it as related to *polypus* at all.

The only way that we get to a position where *octopodes* is definitely "correct" and *octopi* is definitely "wrong" is by requiring a word coined in the 1700s to follow rules about ancient Latinized Greek plurals that were very inconsistent in ancient Latin, and are explicitly contradicted by similar words in both ancient Latin and Greek in this case.

I personally would avoid both *octopi* and *octopodes* and consider them to be sort of "skunked" plurals.  If you want to use *octopodes* to show off some classical skills, just be aware that, etymologically, you're on somewhat shaky ground.

Comment: Neither *oktopous* nor *oktapous* were "common" in ancient Greek, and neither specifically referred to an **octopus**, rather they were just general adjectives referring to "8-footed" (even a length of 8 feet), and to various animals. Regardless, this is not where Linnaeus got his word. As to form X "is normally found as the plural of" form Y, but not form Z, how do you know? It's not like we have ancient texts declining it in detail. As I understand it, *polypos* is largely a hypothetical (extremely rare?) form appearing in dictionaries to justify the odd declension. Corrections are welcome.

Comment: Given the modern Greek word χταπόδια, why not go for "octopodia"?

Comment: @DanielSank: Well, for one thing, the modern Greek singular stem is different, i.e., χταπόδι, and the Latinized *octopus* has no relationship to it.  If we changed the English singular word to *oktapodi* to be in accordance with modern Greek forms, perhaps there would be an argument for using a modern Greek plural *oktapodia*.  But that's not the singular we have.

Comment: I would say "χταπόδι" and "octopus" have more than zero relation :)  Anyway, yeah I get your point and "octopuses" seems like a reasonable English plural.

Comment: The word for octopus was not “coined by Linnaeus”. ὀκτάπους, with ὀκτα- as the compositional stem of ὀκτω, is attested in this meaning in Alexander Trallianus (a medical writer at the time of Justinian). 
http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.52:4:192.LSJ

Comment: @fdb - Thanks for your comment. I noticed this entry before. A few things: (1) Most if not all dictionaries list the word octopus as coined by Linnaeus. (2) If you claim otherwise, do you have a source for the word "octopus" (not ὀκτάπους, but octopus) appearing before Linneaus anywhere? (3) If your claim is instead that Linnaeus may have done a transliteration from this one (somewhat dubious) substantive usage in a medical treatise, do you have a source for that? I'm happy to correct my answer here, but standard etymology sources claim Linnaeus created this Latin word on analogy to polypus.

Comment: @fdb The use of "Octapous" you cite is a joke about two horses having eight feet between them, not using it as the name for the sea creature. Linnæus named the animal, and without the extra *o* (so, "eightfoot" rather than "eight-footed").

Comment: It's very clear from this answer that "octopus" is definitely a Latinization, and that Latin definitely declined similar words from "-us" to "-i"; thus while they didn't actually use "octopus" they would very obviously have pluralized it as "octopi" if they had. If English were using the Greek "oktopous" instead, then sure, "oktopodes" would be correct and "oktopi" wrong, but that's not what we use in English, we use the Latinized form. Simple as.

Comment: @OutisNemo -  'Latin definitely declined similar words from "-us" to "-i"' -- only if they were second declension and masculine.  Words in "us" could be second, third, or fourth declension in Latin, and all formed plurals in different ways.  For example, opus in English forms plural opera, because it was third declension neuter in Latin.  The English plural of "opus" is not "opi."

Comment: @Athanasius: When I wrote "similar words", that was meant to cover what you mention above, i.e. the same declension and gender, and given that "polypus" is precisely that (second declension and masculine), it's very reasonable to expect the equivalent "octopus" to also be that; as your answer mentions, "polypus" did indeed take the plural "polypi".

Answer (score 26):

*Octopuses* and *octopodes* are both correct; the former is appropriate modern English, the latter is most appropriate if you're intentionally trying to come off as a pedantic classicist.  (I use it regularly.)

*Octopoids* is the plural of *octopoid*, not *octopus*.

*Octopi* is a mistaken formation based on interpreting *octopus* as being constructed using a Latin *-us* suffix when it is in fact constructed using a Greek *-pus* suffix.  (I guarantee you that somebody will write an answer that asserts that it has attained correctness through usage.  I contrariwise assert that if ten billion people all jump off a cliff, they're still all stupid.)

(Note: this answer was written for a slightly different question that was merged with the current question, which is why it may seem I was answering oddly.)

Comment: Tell it, brother!

Comment: I'm always tickled to respond to "if [some quantifiers] people all jump off a cliff, then [some bad things]" with this nicely put XKCD comic: http://xkcd.com/1170/

Comment: If the cliff moves, it's the ones who stand still who're stupid.

Comment: If enough people jump off a cliff eventually there will be a nice gentle (if somewhat squishy and smelly) ramp for me to walk down! I reckon for most cliffs this will happen before 10 billion people have jumped off it!

Comment: Is "polypi" equally stupid, in your view? Also, *octopoid* seems to assume the existence of a root *octop(o)-,* so it seems like you should consider it an equally mistaken formation.

Answer (score 7):

The NOAD has the following note about the plural of octopus:

> USAGE The standard English plural of *octopus* is *octopuses*. However, the word *octopus* comes from Greek, and the Greek plural form is *octopodes*. Modern usage of *octopodes* is so infrequent that many people mistakenly create the erroneous plural form *octopi*, formed according to rules for Latin plurals.

Answer (score 2):

Plural forms of **Octopus** is: **octopuses** */ˈɒktəpʊsɪz/*, **octopi** */ˈɒktəpaɪ/*, or **octopodes** */ɒkˈtɒpədiːz/* . See [Terminology of Octopus from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopus#Terminology).

Comment: Octopi is a basterdised plural form, created out of ignorance. (It would be correct if the word were indeed Latin, but it's in fact Greek in origin.)

Answer (score 1):

*Octopi* is based on an incorrect assumption, that *octopus* is of Latin derivation, so we shouldn't use it. *Octopuses* sounds funny, so I wouldn't use it. *Octopodes* may be rare, but it's right, so perhaps it's up to us to get people used to it.