# Once and for all: What's the plural form of "Octopus"?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Octopuses”, “octopi”, or “octo”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270/octopuses-octopi-or-octo)

I've heard octopi, octopuses, octopodes, octopoids, and every time someone uses any of those, all people in the surrounding area immediately launch into an argument about which it is.

So, which one is the actual plural form of octopus?