# Is there a plural of "metropolis", not "metropolises", that would sound better in a less formal register?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-number, register

I am aware that the plural of metropolis is metropolises, but to me it sounds stilted and to be honest I cannot recall ever hearing it used.

Is there an irregular plural of metropolis that would be in a less formal register. Any common mistaken pluralizations?

Comment: If "metropolises" sounds stilted to you, use "cities".

Comment: Actually, wouldn't it be: metropolese as a plural for metropolis?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Metropolis* is originally a Greek word, but comes to English through Latin. The Latin plural is *metropoles* (presumably pronounced with /iːz/ instead of /ɪs/). The Greek plural is *metropoleis*. If you look at a Google Ngram, *metropolises* is used most of the time, but *metropoles* is not uncommon. *Metropoleis* is used very rarely, and when used,  it mainly refers to ancient Greek city-states.

[image: Ngram: metropolis, metropoles, metropoleis]

Wiktionary and some dictionaries suggest *metropolises* and *metropoleis* as the plural, but I would strongly advise against using *metropoleis* (unless you're talking about ancient Greek city-states); Greek plurals are rarely used in English (see *[octopodes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270/octopuses-octopi-or-octo)*). But if you want to use *metropoles* rather than *metropolises*, you won't be alone.

Comment: I still suggest Metropolitan areas...

Comment: ... but if OP started using metropoleis, it would be less-rarely used. I mean, if it's used at all, and not really confusing, why not promote its use over, say metropoles? Greek is teh best :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Metropolises* is the plural of *metropolis*, and for what I know, there aren't other plurals for that word.

Looking for *metropolises* at the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* and the *British National Corpus*, I get the [following data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkds3.png):

[image: Chart]

(*Corpus of Contemporary American English* doesn't report any data under "non-academic" or "miscellaneous"; the scale is logarithmic.)

The higher number of times the word is found in the CoCA corpus is 31, which means a ratio of 0.38 per million.

*Metropolises* is used in sentences like the following:

> I would refine this further to suggest that when experiences in small towns, ports, commercial cities, and industrial **metropolises** are compared, similarities far outweigh divergences across the country and that a broadly defined "Jewishkeit," or mixture of Jewish tradition, custom, values, and historical experience, exerted substantial influence over behavior.

Answer (score -1):

According to dictionary.reference.com the plural for metropolis is "metropolises".

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/metropolis

Comment: That’s not really a citable source.