# Plural form of Octopus and Radius

Tags: grammatical-number, latin, greek

I have recently found this video online from Merriam Webster saying the plural form of octopus is in fact octopuses. The video explains how octopus comes from the Greek language and thus it would be incorrect to say octopi since that is a latin plural form. The Greek plural of octopus would be octopodes, but octopus actually turns into an English word which makes the plural octopuses.

With that being said, why do dictionaries have octopi listed as the plural form if that is incorrect? Is the plural so widely misused that they just threw in octopi in there?

And then there is the Latin word radius. No one ever uses the word radiuses however it is listed in the dictionary. In fact, even my google chrome and firefox spell checker tells me radiuses is incorrect. Is this word never meant to be used? Despite radius also being an English word, people will always say radii for the plural version.

Comment: http://grammarist.com/usage/octopi-octopuses/

Comment: Oh I didn't even know octopus can also be plural as it is. The dictionaries didn't even mention that.

Comment: Related: [What is the correct plural of octopus?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270/what-is-the-correct-plural-of-octopus)

Comment: It's *radii* of circles, but *radiuses* when talking of arm-bones.

Comment: I'm not really asking what the correct plural form of octopus and radius are, but rather why is octopi accepted in the dictionary if it is wrong. The Merriam Webster dictionary contradicts its own statement. And then the word radiuses should also be correct, but spell checkers and teachers will say otherwise. I understand that radius is both a Latin and English word, however we are speaking English and no one uses its English plural form.

Comment: If not for anything, this question shouldn't be a duplicate. I have indicated in the post that I already understand the correct plural of octopus radius. My question pertains more to the usage of the two words.

Comment: I agree. This is wider, with *octopi* being an example, to a more general question of what is or isn't considered a "real" word.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It can be radiuses or radii for either of them. It's just that mathematicians prefer being hypercorrect ("*Beyond* correct? Yes, please...") and surgeons have enough to deal with already to bother with translingual plurals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Octopi* is an example of a hypercorrection.

Some people know that English often uses plurals according to the rules of the language a word came from. (It's not strange that this happens, since such words after all aren't English in origin, so the difference is between borrowing a word and then pluralising it, or borrowing the plural word.)

These people also know that with such words, use of the English plural form is sometimes considered incorrect. They further know that, justly or unjustly, where there is a choice, the use of the non-English form is sometimes considered cleverer, because it requires further knowledge.

*Virii* is another common example, which may have started as a joke. Indeed, several such cases did; *penii* being a more more obvious example of it being a joke rather than an earnest mistake.

*Opus* is an interesting case, because *opuses* and *opera* are both found, following English and Latin rules respectively, but also *opi*, following Latin rules incorrectly; so we have both an English, a Latin, and a hypercorrect Latin form.

A hypercorrection, or any other mistake, can eventually become part of a language if followed by enough people. Since a language exists in a medium of loose consensus, then even if we don't like this, it'll be the case. An example that's dying out again (and isn't about plurals) is that for a long time *foetus* was the more common spelling than *fetus*, though the latter became the more common spelling in America some time ago, and elsewhere quite recently. Yet *foetus* is a hypercorrection of what in Latin was originally *fetus*. Indeed, I'll still spell it *foetus* even though I know this because it's the spelling I'm used to.

Now, when we come to dictionaries, it depends on the purpose of the dictionary in question.

A dictionary like the OED would be remiss in not mentioning *octopi*, because *octopi* is used considerably, and it's the job of the OED to record this.

With other dictionaries, there's a good argument to be made for not including it. Arguments for including it though would be:

1. Someone who came across *octopi* and looked it up, should be given an answer (perhaps with a note saying "incorrect" or "proscribed", perhaps not).
2. The usage panel may have decided that it's so heavily used as to count as a plural that came from an error, rather than an error.

> In fact, even my google chrome and firefox spell checker tells me radiuses is incorrect.

This is a case that certainly shouldn't allow *octopi*; the only reason for a spell-check dictionary is to spell something correctly. Even if we were to edge toward the idea that *octopi* had been fully absorbed into the language as a new plural, while *octopuses* remains common and easy to guess at if you're confused by "why did it say that wasn't the word I wanted?" then it serves no real purpose at all.

If anything, spell-check dictionaries are too forgiving for their purposes; if one mistypes and accidentally produces an obscure word it's better to have it flagged even if there's no doubt it is indeed a word; you can add it yourself if you've cause to use it often.

Comment: Excellent answer. Spell checker finds both radiuses and octopi to be incorrect. Funny how that works out.

Comment: A related question, is whether spell-checks should allow *adduct*, as both LibreOffice and Firefox's do. Now, AFAIK, the only way to spell *adduct* is as I have it here, but if it appears in a piece of writing is it more likely to be intended a typo for *abduct* or a thinko for *adduce*? I'd say it would be better to let those who are likely to write about adduction add the word (or perhaps select a topic they write about that imports a relevant extra dictionary), and then then people who intended *abduct* or *adduce* can have their error flagged.

Answer (score 3):

The OED gives the plurals of *octopus* as *octopuses, octopi, octopodes* in that order, describing *octopi* as ‘rare’. It also describes *radiuses* as ‘rare’, compared with *radii*. The choice, however, is one of style. My own preference is to form an English plural with ‘-(e)s’ wherever possible, because I think anything else sounds stilted. So, for me, *octopuses*, certainly, but there are not many occasions on which I would need to use it. The occasions on which I might require the plural of *radius* are rarer still, but I think I’d be tempted to use *radiuses*, just to annoy those who think they know a bit of Latin.

Comment: In the previous Iraq adventure there were lots of journalist showing off by using "courts martial" as the plural.

Comment: @mgb are you sure "court martials" has over-taken "courts martial" as the plural?

Comment: @JonHanna - no but it should.

Comment: @mgb. Such evidence as there is favours _courts martial_, for which there are 22 records in the COCA, 3 in the BNC and 23 in the OED. The figures for _court martials_ are 6, 0 and 3. This Ngram confirms these findings: http://tinyurl.com/d4qq6tj

Comment: @mgb when pluralising any noun with a post-positive adjective, it's still generally more common to pluralise the noun rather than the adjective, *heirs apparent*, *Pounds sterling*, *best rooms available* rather than *heir apparents*, *Pound sterlings*, *best room availables*.

Comment: @Jon Hanna. Those who wanted to could object that _court martial_ isn't a noun followed by an adjective, but a compound noun, in a way that those others are not.

Comment: I'll certainly agree that it could become a single compound noun, and those using *court martials* are certainly treating it like that. It'd be more likely if it were a loan phrase, rather than English, but even then we have *Brigadier Generals*. I'm more questioning the idea that "it should" do this, when *court* is a very common English noun and *martial* a pretty common English adjective in the context (that is, not very common, but pretty common when you start talking about war or the military). There's no reason to insist it couldn't, but no reason to suggest it "should" either.

Comment: @BarrieEngland my main object was that writers were making a statement (that there multiple trials) less clear in order to show off their knowledge of french  grammer. In the same way that it might be 'clever' on some level to say octopodes, but on the level of communicating the fact that there are multiple molluscs - then octopuses is better

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural_form_of_words_ending_in_-us) acknowledges the issue you being up, and in term mentions that the Oxford English Dictionary does as well.

> The Oxford English Dictionary[9] lists octopuses, octopi and octopodes (in that order); it labels octopodes "rare", and notes that octopi derives from the mistaken assumption that octōpūs is a second declension Latin noun, which it is not. Rather, it is (Latinized) Ancient Greek, from oktṓpous (ὀκτώπους), gender masculine, whose plural is oktṓpodes (ὀκτώποδες). If the word were native to Latin, it would be octōpēs ('eight-foot') and the plural octōpedes, analogous to centipedes and mīllipedes, as the plural form of pēs ('foot') is pedes. In modern Greek, it is called khtapódi (χταπόδι), gender neuter, with plural form khtapódia (χταπόδια).

In short, the answer to your question is **yes**; these words are in use and are mentioned in official sources only because the incorrect forms have seen such widespread use.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is far better to use plurals in the English style. Though OCTOPUSES and OCTOPI are correct as the plural of OCTOPUS, we should give preference to OCTOPUSES.

Comment: But there's no language by which *octopi* should be correct, which is the point of the question; It should logically be either *octopodes* or *octopuses*. The question is why *octopi* is also allowed.