# Plural of Ethos

Tags: grammatical-number, greek

What is the plural form of *ethos*? I have always thought it was "ethoi," but I'm not sure.

Comment: Wiktionary gives _ethoi_ as a/the 'hypercorrect' plural and _ethoses_ as a/the 'nonstandard' plural of _ethos_. Neither is much used if one is to believe Google data, though _ethoses_ seems to be the less uncommon choice. 'Ethoi' is apparently what one would expect the Greek plural to be _if ethos were a masculine noun_. I'd  go with the modern trend to use more standardised forms, and use _ethoses_, which is more transparent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ethos is neutral in Greek, thus ethe would be the Greek thing to say..

Comment: @gsamaras natural over on GLU, possibly.

Answer (score 6):

Since there are two reputable seeming answers (one in comments), I though I would sort out which plural is correct: **ethoi**, **ethea** or **ethe**.

#### Ethoi

Edwin Ashworth in the comments is right to say that the hypercorrect plural is *ethoi* (as per [Wikitionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ethoi)).

> 1. (hypercorrect) plural of ethos

I would, however, like to define what Wiktionary means by *hypercorrect*:

> **[hypercorrect](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#hypercorrect)**
>   **Incorrect** because of the misapplication of a standard rule; for example, *octopi* used as the plural form of *octopus* is hypercorrect because -us → -i is the rule for forming plurals of originally-masculine nouns of the Latin second declension, whereas *octopus* actually derives from Ancient Greek and has the plural form **octopodes** consistent with its etymology.

It is important to note that hypercorrect words are explicitly *incorrect*.

Not **ethoi** then.

#### Ethe

As Uli Troyo has partly explained, this is the *contracted* form of the Ancient Greek plural.

> From the Ancient Greek ἤθη ‎(ḗthē), the **contracted** nominative plural form of ἦθος ‎(êthos).

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

#### Ethea

> From the Ancient Greek ἤθεα ‎(ḗthea), the uncontracted nominative plural form of ἦθος ‎(êthos).

As far as I can tell, there is no semantic difference between the contracted and uncontracted plurals.

Finally, it is worth mentioning that since it has assimilated into English, **ethoses** is acceptable (and probably far wider recognised), even if it lacks etymological backing.

Comment: See [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/138236/47827) for a more detailed treatment of _octopus_. (Also, I think you're missing an a in the last header.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Right you are! That could have been confusing!

Comment: empirically, [ethe](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ethoses%2Cethe%2Cethea%2Cethoi&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cethoses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cethe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cethea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cethoi%3B%2Cc0) seems to rule

Comment: As modern Greek, I would expect ethe, but maybe it's the Greek instinct talking . . I agree with @MichaelChirico...

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikitionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ethos), it can either be "ethe" or "ethea".

> *Origin*:
>   From the Ancient Greek *ἤθεα* (ēthea), the uncontracted nominative plural form of *ἦθος* (ēthos).

Comment: Personally, I think "ethea" sounds much cooler, as in "the respective ethea of two nations".