# Word for nouns with multiple plural forms

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

Some nouns have multiple plurals, this [article from Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/tricky-plural-words-explained/syllabuses-syllabi) names a few. I'm wondering if there is a word to describe this, a word meaning *having multiple plural forms*. To put it in a sentence (two sentences to allow noun and adjective answers):

1. *Syllabus is a(n) (insert word), because it has two plural forms*.
2. *Syllabus is (insert word), because it has two plural forms*.

I have scanned through [the Wikipedia page on English plurals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals) which has a lot of terms for different plural forms, however, I have not come across a term for words with multiple plural forms. I've also scanned through some [blogs on the Oxford Dictionaries website](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/?s=plural), but to no avail.

Some of the examples from the aforementioned Merriam Webster article:

> One referendum, multiple referendums or referenda [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/tricky-plural-words-explained/syllabuses-syllabi)
>
> One syllabus, multiple syllabuses or syllabi [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/tricky-plural-words-explained/syllabuses-syllabi)
>
> One gymnasium, multiple gymnasiums or gymnasia [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/tricky-plural-words-explained/syllabuses-syllabi)
>
> One referendum, multiple referendums or referenda [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/tricky-plural-words-explained/syllabuses-syllabi)
>
> One miasma, multiple miasmas, miasmata or miasms [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/tricky-plural-words-explained/syllabuses-syllabi)
>
> One terminal, multiple terminuses or termini [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/tricky-plural-words-explained/syllabuses-syllabi)

Comment: There's also [octopus](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270/what-is-the-correct-plural-of-octopus/271), which has ***three*** fairly well-known alternative plural forms. But if there's a special term for such words (unlikely, imho, since it wouldn't often be useful), I can't see it anywhere on that earlier ELU question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers there is a term called [double plural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_plural), which refers to plural forms which use an extra suffix (imagine _medias_ being the plural for _medium_).  The Dutch kind(er)(en), meaning children is an example of that.

Comment: Until I looked it up after seeing it in your question, I didn't  realise ***miasm*** existed as an alternative to ***miasma*** (also as a borrowing from German for the homeopathy sense *an acquired or inherited tendency or predisposition to a particular disease*). I'm not sure if that really means ***miasma*** has three plural forms, or whether it might make more sense to say it has two singular forms - one of which has two plural forms, whereas the other is completely regular.

Comment: They're all loanwords (or possibly words coined from loaned roots) in various stages of naturalization; perhaps that will help in the search.

Comment: They all seem to have [peaked in the 19th century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=miasma%2Cmiasmas%2Cmiasmata%2Cmiasms%2Cmiasm&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmiasma%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmiasmas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmiasmata%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmiasms%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmiasm%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: So, did you make up a word? Perhaps *polypluric*?

Comment: @jxh I just asked the question out of interest. I don't have a specific need for the word. If I did need it in writing I'd probably say **word with multiple plural forms**, so it's easily understood (unless it later turns out that there is a word for it, in which case I would explain that word to the reader when first using it and then continuing with that word). ;)

Comment: @JJJ perhaps **word with multi plural orthography**

Comment: @ubihatt nice suggestion, do you have any source using it as such? If you do, please submit it as an answer so I can up vote it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [A University Grammar of English](https://books.google.com/books?id=aiSitM1zmzYC&pg=PA100&dq=Foreign+plurals&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizrZHYkNrcAhXOfn0KHeoeB9IQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=Foreign%20plurals&f=false)
By Randolph Quirk.

> **Foreign plurals** (Nouns) often occur along with **regular plurals** (nouns). They are commoner in technical usage, whereas the **-s** plural is more natural in everyday language; thus **formulas**(general)~**formulae** (in mathematics), **antennas** (general and in electronics) ~ **antennae** (in biology).

Foreign plural nouns often make their plural according to the orthography of the language they were taken from (e.g. Latin or Greek or Italian etc.,).

For a given word, sometimes **foreign plural** and **regular plural** nouns  have different meanings e.g. **medium** has two plurals: **mediums**/**media**, both plural forms have different meanings.

There is a exhaustive explanation in Lesson XVIII of [A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=xVEXAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA41&dq=Foreign+plurals&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGl939kdrcAhUGLY8KHUtUDvMQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=Foreign%20plurals&f=false) By George Payn Quackenbos.

> > So, whenever there is more than one plural form of the given noun, then you can individually refer them as **foreign plural** and/or **regular plural** according to their orthography.

Comment: Not all words with multiple plural forms are foreign. The plural for *mouse* is *mice*, **unless** you're talking about part of the rigging of a ship, in which case it is *mouses*.